# Get specific object in list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have a department object, and that object contains a list of employees. How do I get a department that a specific employee works in? I have a generic `FindAll`

```
IQueryable<Department> FindAll(params Expression<Func<Department, object>>[] includeProperties)
```

I then tried

```
FindAll().Where(x => x.Employee.Any(y => y.Name == name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Im guessing `.Name` is a String. Should it not be `y.Name.Equals(name)`

Comment: Aren't there any built in function in entity framework like `Find()`?

Comment: Please show your `deparment` model

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to load a related entity?

You could do this:

```
    var employee = context.Employee.FirstOrDefault(y=>y.Name==name);
    if(employee!=null)
    {
      context.Entry(employee).Reference("Department").Load();
      var deparment = employee.Department;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `context.Entry(employee)` (lower-case e on employee)? And shouldn't it be `var department = employee.Department`?